# sencha dataitem datamap setItems

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to follow the kitten example given here
http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2#comment_form

I have complex components in which one of the properties of my data is a list of objects. I'm mapping my list object to Ext.Container with setItems method. However, it doesn't seem to work. At the alert point I get the object as undefined. But if I change setItems to setText, then I get the string representation of the object.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

```
Ext.define('MyListItem', {

    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    requires: ['Ext.Container'],
    xtype: 'mylistitem',   

    config: {
        sponsor: true,
        dataMap: {
            getSponsor: {
                setItems: 'sponsor'
            }
        }
    },

    applySponsor: function(config) {
        // I put an alert here to see if I get getSponsor() but the object I get here is undefined
        alert(this.getSponsor());
        return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Container, this.getSponsor());
    },

    updateSponsor: function(newNameButton, oldNameButton) {
        if (oldNameButton) {
            this.remove(oldNameButton);
        }

        if (newNameButton) {
            this.add(newNameButton);
        }
    },

    onSponsorTap: function(button, e) {
        var sponsors = record.get('sponsor');
        //my specific action
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Sponsors', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype:'Sponsors_m',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'level', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'sponsor', type: 'Sponsor'}
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Sponsor', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype:'Sponsor_m',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'image', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'url', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'description', type: 'auto'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

you don't have any field called 'sponsor' in your model

```
config: {
    sponsor: true,
    dataMap: {
        getSponsor: {
            ***setItems: 'sponsor'*** //this supposed to map your component to the datafield
        }
    }
},
```

try changing the bolded font to your field name (setItems: 'name')

and if i'm not mistaken there is strict rule about parameter naming for the update method which is:
***taking "sponsor" as example for config name

> newSponsor, oldSponsor

so the update method for sponsor should be:

```
updateSponsor: function(**newSponsor**, **oldSponsor**) {
        if (oldSponsor) {
            this.remove(oldSponsor);
        }

        if (newSponsor) {
            this.add(newSponsor);
        }
    },
```